# Ruby Regular Expression: 1-2 digits required after period if period is present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create a regular expression that matches the following:

- one or more digits
- allow zero to 1 period after the first digits
- if a period is present

  - require 1 - 2 digits after the period

Here is the regex I have so far, it doesn't work for all cases:

```
/\d{1,}\.{0,1}\d{1,2}/
```

All of these test cases should pass

```
1.9
1
12
1211.1
121234.14
```

All of these test cases should not pass

```
z
z1
z.5         
z.55        # no letters
 .9         # required one or more digits before the period if period is present
34.         # required 1-2 digits after period if period is present
4..3
4..55       # only 1 period
4.333       # only 1-2 digits after period
111,222.44  # no comma
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITED**

I think it will resolve..

```
/^\d{1,}(\.\d{1,2}){0,1}$/
```

My test case:

```
2.3.0 :129 > regex = /^\d{1,}(\.\d{1,2}){0,1}$/
 => /^\d{1,}(\.\d{1,2}){0,1}$/
2.3.0 :161 > regex.match("1.9")
 => #<MatchData "1.9" 1:".9"> 
2.3.0 :162 > regex.match("1")
 => #<MatchData "1" 1:nil> 
2.3.0 :163 > regex.match("12")
 => #<MatchData "12" 1:nil> 
2.3.0 :164 > regex.match("1211.1")
 => #<MatchData "1211.1" 1:".1"> 
2.3.0 :165 > regex.match("121234.14")
 => #<MatchData "121234.14" 1:".14"> 
2.3.0 :166 > regex.match("z")
 => nil 
2.3.0 :167 > regex.match("z1")
 => nil 
2.3.0 :168 > regex.match("z.5")
 => nil 
2.3.0 :169 > regex.match("z.55")
 => nil 
2.3.0 :170 > regex.match(" .9")
 => nil 
2.3.0 :171 > regex.match("34.")
 => nil 
2.3.0 :172 > regex.match("4..3")
 => nil 
2.3.0 :173 > regex.match("4..55")
 => nil 
2.3.0 :174 > regex.match("4.333")
 => nil 
2.3.0 :175 > regex.match("111,222.44")
 => nil
```

Comment: per the post .95 should not match without a leading #

Comment: @meves thanks so much for your response.  I apologize but I changed my question up to make the requirements for the regex clearer because I made some typos.  After looking into it: .95, and .9 should not pass because they require a digit in front.  so: 1.95 and 1.9 would pass. My apologies.  Your answer was correct had I not fixed my post to what I had intended it to be.

Comment: Nice one. Two small points. 1. `\d{1,}` is customarily written `\d+`. 2. You have used ends-of-line anchors. Since there is just one line, that's fine, but I think it's better practice to use "ends-of-string" anchors: `\A` and `\z`.

Answer (score 1):

```
r = /
    \A             # match beginning of string
    \d+            # match >=1 digits
    (?!\d)         # do not match a digit (negative lookahead)
    (?:\.\d{1,2})? # optionally match a period and 1 or 2 digits in a non-capture group
    \z             # match end of string
    /x             # free-spacing regex definition mode

"312.64"  =~ r #=> 0
"312.643" =~ r #=> nil
"3.64"    =~ r #=> 0
"a3.64"   =~ r #=> nil
"a.64"    =~ r #=> nil
"23.a64"  =~ r #=> nil
"31"      =~ r #=> 0
```

This regex is customarily written

```
r = /\A\d+(?!\d)(?:\.\d{1,2})?\z/
```